# determine code size

Tags: gcc

I have library intended for embedded devices developed in C for which I need to compute the code size. The OS is Linux and compiler is gcc. Could you please indicate how this can be done? Also are there ways in which I can reduce the foot print size using mechanisms like compiler optimization?

Comment: ` man size `.  compilers allow you to optimize for space, `-O1` I believe in g++

Comment: `-Os` is optimization for size.

Also, I find `nm -S --size-sort` useful, to find the worst offenders.

Answer (score 0):

gcc will do size optimization if the -Os option is given.

The GNU size utility will show the size of object code. See `man size`.